# Managing apps volume in Windows 7

Tags: c++, delphi, audio, windows-7, windows-vista

How can I retrieve the list of application audio sessions (like in Windows volume mixer)
and change volume of one application (for example, Mozilla) manually (C++, Delphi)? Skype do something the same when you start talking (decreases the volume of other applications). Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure that Skype themselves is running code that does this, and that you're not talking about the built-in Windows 7 feature that automatically adjusts the volume of other sounds when it detects communications activity? You know, [this feature](http://superuser.com/a/74117/40134)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To enumerate the Audio sessions you must use the [`IAudioSessionManager2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd370950%28VS.85%29.aspx) interface and call the [GetSessionEnumerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd370952%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method, this will return a [`IAudioSessionEnumerator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd370950%28VS.85%29.aspx) interface , from here you must invoke the [`GetSession`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd368286%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method to return a [`IAudioSessionControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd368246%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) interface wich provides all the functions to retrieve the info related to the audio sessions. as additional lecture try the this MSDN article [`Default Ducking Experience`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd316773%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).